# Переключение между Activity [Navigation Drawer] в Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-drawer

Создал activity - Navigation Drawer Activity - написал код к главной странице (main page), напиал код к второму активиту (starters) и создал третий activity (main_course). Я не могу понять как переключаться между активити. Когда я в боковом меню выбираю переход на любое активити с main page, то все рабоет, а когда я перешел, допустим в starters, я не могу перейти с данного активити дальше [ в main_course].

Подскажите мне ресурсы где я могу посмотреть переключение между активити (Желательно не вставлять ссылки на developer.android.com ), ошибку в коде или совет.

код main page:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.starters) {
        // Handle the camera action
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, starters.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.main_course) {
        // Handle the camera action
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, main_course.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.desserts) {

    } else if (id == R.id.drink) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
} }
```

код starters:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class starters extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private static final String TAG = "starters";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starters);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, 

R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 

R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(false);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);



    //Here will menu list:
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");
    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_starters);

    //Creating list:
    Starters_menu cheeseburger = new Starters_menu("Cheeseburger", "Cheese, Tomato, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Onion");

    //Parsing in Array
    ArrayList<Starters_menu> startersList = new ArrayList<>();
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);
    startersList.add(cheeseburger);

    StartersListAdapter adapter = new StartersListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_starters, startersList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.starters) {
        // Handle the camera action
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, starters.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.main_course) {
        //Handle the camera action
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, main_course.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.desserts) {

    } else if (id == R.id.drink) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такого функционала лучше всего подходит Fragments.
Пример как сделать ваш функционал лучше:
[https://medium.com/@cryptograph2013/navigation-drawer-android-программирование-навигационные-структуры-в-android-javaфрагментарны-a4d881a04e78](https://medium.com/@cryptograph2013/navigation-drawer-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-android-java%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B-a4d881a04e78)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! как раз решил проблему через Fragments